# {assumption, apply, intro} is sufficient for min prop logic

Tags: coq

I read that the set `{assumption, apply, intro}` of tactics from `Ltac` is sufficient to prove any tautology in the minimal constructive propositional logic.

I suppose that a *pen-and-paper* proof of this claim is done by induction on the syntax of a tautology by showing that the 3 tactics can build incrementally a term that represent the tautology.

I am interested to know if an alternative proof **inside** Coq using `Ltac` or other meta-language could be possible.

It would mean that Ltac or an alternative meta-language could reflect on what these tactics really do and could manipulate them as variables.

I am much interested in a positive answer in this direction even if it is a bit contrived.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, just `apply` is sufficient.  Just apply a proof term with the correct type.  Or to be really lean, don't use any Ltac at all, just assign the proof term with

**Definition** name : < *proposition* > := < *proof term* >.

Example:

```
Lemma has_next :  forall n, exists n', S n = n'.
Proof. 
  intro n. 
  exists (S n). 
  reflexivity. 
Qed.
```

can be "proved" by giving the proof term directly.

```
Definition has_next : forall n, exists n', S n = n' := fun n => ex_intro  _ (S n) eq_refl.
```

You know, there is nothing magical about the `Ltac` commands. They are just tools that make it easier to create the proof term little by little, but you can supply the whole proof term in one go, if you want to use as few tactics as possible.

The "proof" comes from the fact that you have shown that there really exists a proof term with the required type (the proposition).  And Coq type-checks the term for you, to make sure that the term actually has that type.

Coq doesn't even care how the term was constructed - by divine insight or from a partially buggy program, as long as the term type checks.

Comment: Thx. But the point was that the 3 tactics were sufficient without any additional term from the Calculus of Inductive Construction. Clearly in your first sentence, you propose the apply tactic with CIC terms. I am aware that it is indeed possible and I have used it in other contexts but that is not my question.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood what you were asking for. What would your kind of proof of i.e. `forall P Q, (P \/ Q) -> (Q \/ P).`  look like?

Comment: your lemma is not from minimal propositional logic since it contains "OR" connector. Minimal = application + implication.